# Proving that a rational root of an integer polynomial $f$ has a corresponding polynomial $h$ that is a factor of it

Tags: polynomials, roots

> Say $f(x)\in\mathbb{Z}[x]$ has a root $r \in\mathbb Q$. If $r = \frac{a}{b}$ with $a, b \in\mathbb{Z}$, $b > 0$ and $\gcd(a, b) = 1$, how can we show that there exists a polynomial $g(x) ∈\mathbb{Z}[x]$ with $f(x) = (bx − a)g(x)$?

My preliminary approach here is that for $f(r) = 0$ then there is some $\hat{h}(x)\in \mathbb Q[x]$ with $f(x) = (x −r) \hat{h}(x)$. Now, writing $\hat{h}(x) = \sum^n_{i=0} c_i x_i$, I want to show that we have $c_i \in\mathbb Z$ such that $\forall i\in[0, n]$, $b|c_i$. By simple arithmetic I have $f(x) = (x - \frac{a}{b})(\sum_{i=0}^n \frac{c_i a}{b}x^i)$. Since $f(x)\in\mathbb{Z}[x]$, then $b|a$ and $b|c_i$, and since $a, b$ are coprime, then $b|c_i$ necessarily.

I'm a bit stuck on how to prove that $c_i$ is an integer though. I want to somehow start with the coefficient of $x^0$ to inform $x^1$ etc. and similarly use coefficient of $x^{n+1}$ to give me information on $x^n$ etc.

Comment: Do you know Gauss's lemma?

Comment: If you know Gauss's Lemma then this is a dupe of many prior posts proving that. Otherwise you should  say more about what results you have available.

Comment: Strong Induction on deg $(f)$... (1). Trivial if deg $(f)=0,$ i.e. if $f\equiv 0$... (2). If$deg(f)>0$ then $b$ must be a divisor of the leading co-efficient of $f$ so there exist $i(x), f_1(x)\in \Bbb Z[x] $ with deg ($f_1)<$deg ($f$) and $f(x)=(bx-a)i(x)+f_1(x).$ Now $f_1(a/b)=0.$

Comment: How would one use Gauss' lemma? As in this? https://crypto.stanford.edu/pbc/notes/numbertheory/gausslemma.html